# Display these json images as listview

Tags: android, image, listview

I have successfully parsed my json images and displayed the response as image ,however I can only display one image at a time.

[image]

*How can I display these images as listview using this code.*

Before posting this question I have also looking to this solution. I want to display these images as listview along with my other json values using using the below code.

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

    JSONParser prop = new JSONParser();
    JSONObject json = prop.getJSONFromUrl(url);
    try{
    properties = json.getJSONArray(TAG_PROPERTY);
    for (int i = 0; i < properties.length(); i++) {
        JSONObject c = properties.getJSONObject(i);
        String photoThumbnailUrl = c.getString(TAG_PHOTOS);             

    // load image view control
    imgView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgView);

    // grab image to display
    try {
        imgView.setImageDrawable(grabImageFromUrl(photoThumbnailUrl));


    } catch (Exception e) {
        txtUrl.setText("Error: image not grabed");
    }
   }
    }catch (Exception ex) {
    txtUrl.setText("Error: Properties not recieved");
    }
}
private Drawable grabImageFromUrl(String photoThumbnailUrl) {
    System.out.println(photoThumbnailUrl);
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}
//from here only one image is displayed....
//start the listview here

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        System.out.println("ok");
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        ViewHolder holder;
        if (convertView == null) {
            //convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_items, null);
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.identifier= (TextView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.identifier);
            holder.price = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.price);
            holder.address = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.address);
            holder.photoThumbnailUrl = (ImageView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.imgView);
            convertView.setTag(holder);
            System.out.println("identifier");
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }
        return convertView;
}
    class ViewHolder{
        public TextView identifier;
        public TextView price;
        public TextView address;
        public ImageView photoThumbnailUrl;

    }
    }
```

Many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should create a custom listview item with XML and use a SimpleAdapter to fill each row with the JSON items. A while back is used [this](http://devblogs.net/2011/01/04/custom-listview-with-image-using-simpleadapter/) article to help me out, I hope it helps you as well.

Answer (score 0):

For list views you need to download the new content for each row.

This can be tricky to be done correctly. I have created a helper here:
https://github.com/mufumbo/android-helper/blob/master/src/com/mufumbo/android/helper/ThumbLoader.java

Example of usage:

Make your ViewHolder to implement the {@link ThumbLoader.ThumbEvent} and then when populating the ViewHolder:

ThumbLoader thumbLoaderInstance;

public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

....

thumbLoaderInstance.pushEvent(holder, true);
....

}